# Eliminar caracter extraño (000C)

Tags: php, regex

Estoy intentando capturar y filtrar un caracter extraño que venía con datos externos, lo cual está causando que al lanzarlo como JSON, este no sea válido:

```
$string = preg_replace('/[^\w\dñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚüÜºª\-_\/\s\\<>,;:.*\[\]\(\)+?¿!&%@=]/', '', $string);
```

El caracter aparece en esta línea:

```
Caracter extraño:  (pasa la validación!)
```

Testeando expresión regular en [Regexr](http://regexr.com/3gamj). Como véis, no está siendo capturado (debería estar remarcado con fondo azul).
[image: Testing regular expression on Regexr]

Así es como se muestra en el navegador:

[image: This is how it is displayed in the browser]

Y así es como se muestra en el Pluma (un editor simple de Linux):

[image: this is how it's displayed in Pluma (a Linux editor)]

Cuando copio el caracter en el cortapapeles e intento insertarlo en la búsqueda de Google, no se inserta nada. Es muy extraño. Nunca me había encontrado con algo similar.

Alguna idea de qué hacer?

Comment: Estamos en SO Español, ponlo en castellano porfa.

Comment: Cómo es posible? Si siempre he publicado en el internacional (en inglés). Así tengo más posibilidades de respuesta.

Comment: por algún motivo, me ha redirigido aquí sin darme cuenta. Mis disculpas.

Comment: Aparentemente es el [carácter de Form Feed](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+000C)

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Y cómo me puedo deshacer de él por código?

Comment: @LuisMartin mis conocimientos de [tag:php] son escasos, pero la clasificación del carácter lo considera [*whitespace*](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/bidiclass/WS), la RegEx debería capturarlo como tal ¿no?.

Comment: Con este regex coge todos los caracteres, [^\cp] el especial incluido, pero no consigo separarlo del resto, no se si te servirá de algo.

Comment: @Paper es correcto lo que estás diciendo, ya que `\s`  incluye a `[ \t\r\n\f]`, y por eso no lo está eliminando con `preg_replace()` (no es exclusivo de PHP), y podrías publicar la respuesta

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Como te [comentó PaperBirdMaster](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/85905/problema-al-intentar-capturar-caracter-extra%C3%B1o-con-expresi%C3%B3n-regular#comment158011_85905), el caracter es un [form feed](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000c/index.htm) (o salto de página), cuyo valor ASCII es 12 (o `000C` como te lo muestra en Pluma).

¿Por qué no se está eliminando con `preg_replace()`?

Porque está dentro de la clase de caracteres que estás aceptando. `\s` incluye a [espacios en blanco](http://regular-expressions.mobi/shorthand.html?wlr=1): `[ \t\n\r\f]` (`\f` es este caracter).

**`\s` coincide con:**

- espacio
- tabulación
- salto de línea
- retorno
- salto de página

Si no quisieras incluirlo, reemplaza a `\s` por un espacio (o también incluyendo a `\t`, `\r` o `\n`, como quieras).

```
$string = preg_replace('/[^\wñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚüÜºª\-\/ \t\\<>,;:.*[\]()+?¿!&%@=]/', '', $string);
```

Comment: Perfecto! Así funciona. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Tené en cuenta que en mi respuesta agregué `\t` y no estoy incluyendo saltos de línea... Deberías adaptarlo a tu caso

Comment: Si si. Los he añadido. Gracias!!